# Como colocar Scroll em um layout já feito no Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho esse layout já feito, porém em celulares menores os botões ficam inacessíveis, gostaria de implementar scrolls tanto na vertical quanto na horizontal quando necessário

Esse é o xml do meu layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:visibility="visible"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".controlador.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/banner"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtnsd"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.465"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtmdx"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.465"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtmdy"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.465"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:text="Solicitações:"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:text="Nsd:"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/edtnsd"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="86dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="86dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:text="Mdx:"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/edtmdx"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="86dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="86dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:text="Mdy:"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/edtmdy"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="kN"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edtnsd"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:text="kN.m"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edtmdx"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:text="kN.m"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edtmdy"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/statusbarra"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Analisando..."
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/load" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:onClick="analisar"
    android:text="ANALISAR"
    android:visibility="visible"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtmdy" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/load"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:contentDescription="Analisando..."
    android:progress="0"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/continuar01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:onClick="chamarzx"
    android:text="Proseguir >>"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/load" />

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara é bem simples, na verdade. Você pode simplesmente aninhar as classes VerticalScrollView e HorizontalScrollView para obter o resultado necessário. Veja uma possível solução.

```
<!--layout.xml-->
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Estou iniciando agora no android, como eu colocaria isso no xml? Tentei copiar todo o xml que tá na pergunta para dentro de onde estar comentado, mas todos os elementos somem e o aplicativo fecha ao executar.

Comment: Pronto, vê se agora funciona. Adicionei o namespace Android. E só para lembrar o scrollview só aceita um filho